# Google couldn't crawl your site because we were unable to access your site's robots.txt file

Tags: django, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I verified my site using google webmaster. I have made my website in django and I also added robots.txt. 
Now google is showing green tick mark I think its good on DNS and Server Connectivity but and red warning mark on robots.txt fetch..

My robots.txt looks like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Is that google takes time to crawl site ? or I have errors in my robots.txt or its settings.

When I open robots.txt from my site like `mysite.com/robots.txt` I can see the robots.txt file..

Also when I run robots.txt test in webmaster it gives allowed result..
My site is not even being searched in google..

But why its not crawling my site ?

Answer (score 0):

Google generally caches robots.txt. It tries to recrawls mostly in 24 hrs. If you are sure there is nothing with your robots.txt, you probably have to wait.